# Babel ES6: Import node modules that need to be transpiled in ES6 as well

Tags: node.js, import, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am importing a node module correctly but run into an issue where the node module I am importing is written in es6 and babel is unable to transpile it.

In base class header:

```
import foo from 'bar/lib/foo';
```

in foo.js in node modules:

```
import Debug from 'debug';
export default class foo from bar {
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

Error Message:

```
import Debug from 'debug';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

As you can see it is able to find the file foo.js but it is not running the node module in es6. How can I have Babel transpile both the base code as well as the node module that it is trying to import?

Comment: Are you talking about any specific module?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a file .babelrc with this content?

```
{
   "presets": ["es2015"],
   "plugins": []
}
```

You can check an example here: https://github.com/Talento90/ima-up

Comment: I do within the root of my base folder but not within the node module 'bar' folder. Should it be in there as well?

Comment: How are you transpiling the já files? Via Gulp?

Answer (score 1):

The node module should be compiled separately from your source code. If you are using an external lib, they should have a directory with the transpiled code. If you are writing your own, you need to use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) and compile it separately.

If the node module already has a transpiled directory (like `dist`), you could try importing the transpiled code into the node module:

```
import foo from 'bar/dist/foo';
```